# Use Redis streams for MQTT queue

Tags: redis, stream, queue, stream-processing

Redis has changed a lot in the later years, and it's difficult to keep up with the latest features.

We have a few thousand IoT devices that all send MQTT messages every second. We want different consumers to read and process the messages. Is Redis streams suitable of taking in thousands of messages each second, queuing them, and deleting them when they are processed?